# What is glteximage2d and gltexsubimage2d pixel ordering?

Tags: opengl

I have a few questions on the usage of these two and how they effect textures.

What exactly is the ordering of the pixels? The pixels are provided via a buffer that's continuous. In what order does the texture read them so that they are distributed into the x and y planes?

Also these methods accept a type parameter for the data, does each pixel get 3 values? Because when we use the `texture(uvMap, textureUV)` method in the shader, it returns a vec3 of floats. So how exactly the data we provide to the texture via glteximage2d and gltexsubimage2d is read and organized in open gl?

Here is my assumption, correct me if I'm wrong:

The data buffer contains the pixel data. Each pixel is represented by the 3 values of the type sent in via glteximage2d and gltexsubimage2d methods. So the buffer we provide needs to have 3 * width * height number of values in it. OpenGL reads the buffer as follows(pseudo-code):

```
for(int y range 0 and height)
 for(int x range 0 and width)
   int index= (y * (width * 3))  + (x * 3);
   pixels[y][x].x = buffer[index + 0];
   pixels[y][x].y = buffer[index + 1];
   pixels[y][x].z = buffer[index + 2];
```

Comment: It depends on how you set up the [pixel transfer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer)

Comment: Thanks a ton. That document actually explains it very clearly.  Feel free to leave an answer so i can accept it. @NicolBolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference is very clear about that:

[glTexImage2D](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)

> **Description**
>
> The last three arguments (*format, type, data*) describe how the image is represented in memory.
>
> If target is GL_TEXTURE_2D, ..., data is read from *data* as a sequence of signed or unsigned bytes, shorts, or longs, or single-precision floating-point values, depending on *type*. These values are grouped into sets of one, two, three, or four values, depending on *format*, to form elements.
>
> **The first element corresponds to the lower left corner of the texture image. Subsequent elements progress left-to-right through the remaining texels in the lowest row of the texture image, and then in successively higher rows of the texture image. The final element corresponds to the upper right corner of the texture image.**
>
> *format* determines the composition of each element in *data*. It can assume one of these symbolic values: ... (to be brief, i will not list the elements here, but it is a must read)